# how i can change value of field of a string (format json)?

Tags: java, json

I'm developing a web services in java.

In the service I have to check the value of the 'desagg' field if it is equal to 0 I do not have to do anything while if it is greater than 0 I have to make another query and put the result in place of the value of the 'desArticle' field inside the json

I try to use gson method of google library but i don't think is the right method

```
String sql="SELECT sigdoc as sigla, numdoc as numero, datdoc as data , procor AS seq_articolo, desagg , precorpo.codint as codiceInterno, qtauni AS quantitaArticolo, " + 
                " przuni AS prezzoVendita, (scont0/100) AS sconto1, (scont1/100) AS sconto2, (scont2/100) AS sconto3, impnet AS importoNetto, datcon as dataConsegna, serdoc as chiaveRiga," + 
                " coarfo as codiceArticolo, descri as desArticolo" + 
                " FROM precorpo " + 
                " INNER JOIN anamagge ON precorpo.codint=anamagge.codint " + 
                " WHERE tiprig=0 AND sigdoc='"+sigdoc+"' AND numdoc="+numdoc+"" + 
                " ORDER BY procor;";

try
        {

            json = db.executeQueryTOJSON2(sql);

            JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);

            int result = jobj.get("desagg").getAsInt();

            if (result > 0)
            {
                String query2=" select group_concat(descri) from memodocu where pointm="+result+" group by pointm;";

                ResultSet rs = db.executeQuery(query2);
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    String desc = rs.getString("group_concat(descri)");
                }
            }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("errore "+e);
        }
```

json in output is:

```
[ { "sigla":"PREV" , "numero":1.1000122E7 , "data":"" , "seq_articolo":1 , "desagg":0 , "codiceInterno":25951 , "quantitaArticolo":2.0 , "prezzoVendita":4.62 , "sconto1":0.0000 , "sconto2":0.0000 , "sconto3":0.0000 , "importoNetto":9.24 , "dataConsegna":"" , "chiaveRiga":7379 , "codiceArticolo":"A025951" , "desArticolo":"025951 ARTICOLO DI PROVA" }  , { "sigla":"PREV" , "numero":1.1000122E7 , "data":"" , "seq_articolo":2 , "desagg":100 , "codiceInterno":15879 , "quantitaArticolo":20.0 , "prezzoVendita":2.17 , "sconto1":0.0000 , "sconto2":0.0000 , "sconto3":0.0000 , "importoNetto":43.4 , "dataConsegna":"" , "chiaveRiga":7380 , "codiceArticolo":"A015879" , "desArticolo":"I want to modify this" }  ]
```

I'm a beginner with json

Comment: First of all, you have learn aboute SQL Injection, this is hell : `select group_concat(descri) from memodocu where pointm="+result+" group by pointm;`.

Comment: @Zorglube ok I'll think about that later

Comment: the current problem is that I can not parse the json string

Comment: You really must do it, SQL Injection may be an major security breach.

Comment: @Zorglube ok thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!

```
                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(json);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String tmp = jsonobject.getString("desagg");

                    if(!tmp.equals("0"))//vuol dire che dessagg diverso da 0
                    {
                        String sql2="select group_concat(descri) from memodocu where pointm="+tmp+" group by pointm;";
                        ResultSet rs = db.executeQuery(sql2);
                        String tmp2="";

                        while(rs.next())
                        {
                            tmp2=rs.getString("group_concat(descri)");
                        }
                        jsonobject.put("desArticolo", tmp2);
                    }
```

I used the jsonArray to parse json string and json object to get the value of the field I wanted then if tmp is different from 0 I go to run the query I take the result and update the value of the field desArticle

the final result will end up on the jsonarray variable, to print it you have to do jsonarray.toString ();

Answer (score 0):

Gson is the right way to go, according the doc you can parse the string and then gey a type-value by a given key

here the doc:

https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#getAsInt--

```
JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(mySqlResultAsJson, JsonObject.class);



int result = jobj.get("desagg").getAsInt();

if (result >= 0)
{
    do another request
}
```

Comment: I want to check the value of the field 'desagg'

Comment: then i want to change the value of field 'desArticolo'

Comment: `{ "sigla":"PREV" , "numero":1.1000122E7 , "data":"" , "seq_articolo":2 , "desagg":100 , "codiceInterno":15879 , "quantitaArticolo":20.0 , "prezzoVendita":2.17 , "sconto1":0.0000 , "sconto2":0.0000 , "sconto3":0.0000 , "importoNetto":43.4 , "dataConsegna":"" , "chiaveRiga":7380 , "codiceArticolo":"A015879" , "desArticolo":"I want to modify this" }`

Comment: there is another error :  Expected a com.google.gson.JsonObject but was com.google.gson.JsonArray

Answer (score 0):

If you want parse this :

`{ "sigla":"PREV" , "numero":1.1000122E7 , "data":"" , "seq_articolo":2 , "desagg":100 , "codiceInterno":15879 , "quantitaArticolo":20.0 , "prezzoVendita":2.17 , "sconto1":0.0000 , "sconto2":0.0000 , "sconto3":0.0000 , "importoNetto":43.4 , "dataConsegna":"" , "chiaveRiga":7380 , "codiceArticolo":"A015879" , "desArticolo":"I want to modify this" }`

You might do somthing like ;

```
MyObject myObj = new Gson().fromJson(myJsonStream, MyObject.class);
int desagg = myObj.getDesagg();
```

And define an object like this :

```
class MyObject {
  private String sigla; 
  private float numero; 
  private String data; 
  ...
}
```

Comment: I would like to avoid using the classes

Comment: how I can change the value of the 'desArticle' field?

Comment: Ok, so think about the solution purposed by `Φxocę-웃-Пepeúpa-ツ`, or look into Regular Expression.